# Error Unziping File: error 1 in extracting from zip file

Tags: r, download, operating-system, unzip

I am trying to download and unzip a file from the internet using the following code. I have a PC running on Windows 10.

```
#################### Set Working Directory #################
setwd("C:/Users/Sharif/OneDrive/Data/FEC Data/Committee Information")

#################### Download File ############

download.file("https://www.fec.gov/data/browse-data/?tab=bulk-data/files/bulk-downloads/1980/indiv80.zip", destfile = "1980 - Committee Information.zip")
unzip("1980 - Committee Information.zip") ## Does not work and produces an error
```

For some reason, I get the following error when I run the unzip function and the file does not unzip into my working directory.

```
Warning message:
In unzip("1980 - Committee Information.zip") :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
```

Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on my machine.

```r
download.file("https://www.fec.gov/files/bulk-downloads/1980/indiv80.zip", destfile = "1980_Committee_Information.zip")

unzip("1980_Committee_Information.zip")
```

For some reason, the `url` you are requesting is not downloading the file. Looking into the page source (`View-source` from your browser) reveals the actual `url` used by the website to serve a request.

Comment: Yup! That worked on mine as well. I guess it didn't like the "-"  and/or space in the name ("1980 - Committee Information.zip"). Lesson learned. Thank you very much for the help!